# Confluent Operator add additional connector

Tags: apache-kafka, yaml, operator-keyword, confluent-platform

I have confluent operator setup on OpenShift and this image 'confluentinc/cp-int-container-operator:6.1.0.0' does not include all the connectors.

How to include any additional connector in the yaml, example I need to include the Debezium connect for mysql.

confluent-hub install debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:1.6.0

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-server-connect-operator:6.1.0.0
USER root
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt <connector1>:<connector1-version> \
  && confluent-hub install --no-prompt <connector2>:<connector2-version> \
  && ...
USER 1001
```

https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-configure-connect.html

Comment: my deployment is already done, how can i run this command post deployment. I cannot run this inside the contain as I get SSL exception. Can i include in stateful set for the pod

Comment: @VV This answer is suggesting that you create a new container, upload it to your Openshift Container Registry, then replace the images used by the Operator for Connect with this one